# Memory is not collected even after the GC.Collect()

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I executed the below code many times and always getting 12 bytes of memory difference even after the Garbage collection. Can any one help me, why the below code always maintains the 12 bytes in memory.

```
internal class Test
{
    private List<int> _arrItems;
    //private int[] _arrItems;

    public Test()
    {
        _arrItems = new List<int>();
        //   _arrItems = new int[0];
    }

    internal void Close()
    {
        _arrItems = null;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var totalMemoryBefore = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        {
            var test = new Test();
            test.Close();
            test = null;
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        var totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        Console.WriteLine(totalMemoryBefore + ":All Done:" + totalMemory);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);`?

Comment: The documentation is clear that the number returned by this function is a guess. I don't think you can rely on exact (to the byte) memory values in a managed, garbage-collected environment. I'm just guessing but it's possible the framework itself allocates those bytes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: To get a better idea, get a full process dump before and after the allocation and then compare them using some memory profiler tool. (WinDbg or .Net Memory Profiler, etc.)

Comment: What are you really going to do with that 12 bytes memory? Maybe it is because your code triggers some CLR internal infrastructure code to allocate some memory. Do note that you're not alone in .Net world; GC, CLR, Jit compiler, they all can allocate memory themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I found the cause, Reason is static read only member in List class.

**Static member defined in System.Generic.Collection.List<> class:**

```
static readonly T[]  _emptyArray = new T[0];
```